# Typescript/angular Is there a way to convert a string into an instance variable?

Tags: angular, string, typescript, instance-variables

So I'm making a function that takes in an object and creates a string from it.
The object that is being fed into the function looks something like:

```
  testMessage: {
    alertMessagePreObject0: "Example Text "
    alertMessageObject0: "examples"
    alertMessageKey0: "exampleA" 
    alertMessagePostObject0: "End of Example"
}
```

And my function is currently:

```
handleAlertBody(messageToHandle):string{
    let messageBody: string = '';
      if(messageToHandle['alertMessageObject0']){
        let objectToRead = messageToHandle['alertMessageObject0'];
        let objectKey = messageToHandle['alertMessageKey0'];
        let insertion = objectToRead[objectKey];
        messageBody += messageToHandle + messageToHandle['alertMessagePreObject0'] + insertion + messageToHandle['alertMessagePostObject0'];
      } else {
        messageBody = 'no object provided';
      }
      return messageBody; 
    }
```

If I had an existing object within the class called examples such that examples[exampleA] = "middle text" then I would want my function to return "Example Text middle text End of Example" when handleAlertBody(testMessage) is called. However, it is currently returning "Example Text undefined End of Example". I know this is because examples doesn't exist within the class, only this.examples does. I tried changing the line where insertion is defined to be `let insertion = this.objectToRead[objectkey]` but it obviously throws an error because there is nothing defined in  the class called objectToRead. Is there any way to convert the string of "examples" into an instance variable of this.examples? Or is there another way to achieve the desired result given the above object? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using TypeScript, you can create a Class setting up the attributes that you want to use. Then, you will make a new instance of this class, when calling the matchObject.

For example:

```
class Example {
    _message1: string = "message"
   // ...any message

    constructor() {}
}

var obj = {
    x: new Example()
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that's not what I needed. Perhaps a better way to phrase my question would be to say that I need a way to match the input of "example" with an instance variable this.example.  If I need to clarify the question at all let me know. Thanks